# Making a function to access a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need to make a function that will allow me to access the dictionary I made, so when you type in the entry box "bug" or "algortihim" it will display their definition in the text box.

i am calling the function "click" and if you look at he variable button_1, you can see there is an action called command=click. That is the name of the function but i have not made the function yet.

the dictionary is called my_compdictinary

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font



root = tk.Tk()

HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH=600



canvas = tk.Canvas(root,height = HEIGHT, width = WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

upper_frame = tk.Frame(canvas, bg="black")
upper_frame.place(relx=0, rely=0,relwidth=3,relheight=0.8,anchor="center")

my_compdictinary = {
    "algorithm": "step by step instructions to complete a task", "bug":"piece of code that causes something to fail"
}


upper_label= tk.Label(upper_frame,text="A Computer Science Glossary\nby",font="courie",fg="white", bg="black")
upper_label.place(relx=0.6,rely=0.5)
tk.Label(upper_frame,text="ahc",font="courie 16 bold",fg="white", bg="black").place(relx=0.648,rely=0.57)

tk.Label(upper_frame,text="http://www.ahc.me.uk/",font="courie 10",fg="gold", bg="black").place(relx=0.622,rely=0.62)

tk.Label(upper_frame,text="Enter the word you would like a defintion for:",font="courie 12",fg="white", bg="black").place(relx=0.5,rely=0.78)

entry=tk.Entry(upper_frame, font=("courier", 12))
entry.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.83)
button_1=tk.Button(upper_frame, text = "SUBMIT", command=click,font="courie 10")
button_1.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.89)

tk.Label(upper_frame,text="Definition:",font="courie 12",fg="white", bg="black").place(relx=0.5,rely=0.95)

output= tk.Text(root,width=50,height=50)
output.place(relx=0,rely=0.43)

#my_compdictinary = {
    #"algorithm": "step by step instructions to complete a task", "bug":"piece of code that causes something to fail"
#}

lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="black")
lower_frame.place(relx=1,rely=1,relwidth=2,relheight=0.3, anchor="center")

bottom_label=tk.Label(lower_frame,text="click here to exit:", fg="white", bg="black")
bottom_label.place(relx=0,rely=0)

bottom_button = tk.Button(lower_frame, text= "Exit")
bottom_button.place(relx=0, rely=0.1,width=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does `cmd=my_compdictinary.get` work?

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
In [18]: my_compdictinary = {
    ...:     "algorithm": "step by step instructions to complete a task", "bug":"piece of code that causes something to fail"
    ...: }

In [21]: def click(keyword):
    ...:     return my_compdictinary.get(keyword, "")

In [22]: click("algorithm")
Out[22]: 'step by step instructions to complete a task'

In [23]: click("something")
Out[23]: ''
```

`.get` function is used on a dictionary to return the value if the key is present and also,  we can pass a default value which will be returned if the key is not present in the dictionary.